# Matlab 3 dB 12 hertz lowpass filter

Tags: matlab, filtering, lowpass-filter

I am looking for a 3dB low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 12Hz. I know Matlab has this function `fdesign.lowpass` and it should be possible to be 3dB with `F3db` ([source](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/signal/ref/fdesign.lowpass.html) / [additional](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/dsp/ug/a-simple-fir-filter-design.html?searchHighlight=lowpass)) but I'm not really sure yet how to implement them, that is: what features I should include and what features not. I get confused by all the other variables I think I don't need -- I just need Fc and 3dB. I also found `fdatool` but also don't really know how to set such a filter.

The data contains regular x and y values while it will be a speed versus time plot of a recorded movement.

Comment: What should 3dB represent? Cut-off frequency is defined as one where attenuation of filter is 3dB, so 3dB requirement doesn't add additional info.

Comment: I don't really know, I read about it somewhere. And there's the thing that you can specifically add F3db and default is 6dB (?), see help `fdesign.lowpass`.
But let's say it doesn't matter: what values/variables should I enter to filter my matrix?

Comment: To filter your matrix you should know sampling frequency for both dimensions. Actually that info about 6dB could make sense: 1D filter would have cut-off frequencies with 3dB attenuation, and when two filters of those kind are used to create 2D filter, point in frequency response (fco_1, fco_2) would have attenuation of 6dB. To get the 3dB attenuation at that point you would have to take square root of original 2D filter... But this is too much guessing on my part and you should try to study problem a bit more.

Comment: I don't know the exact sampling frequency because of this special data -- dt varies between 0.01-¹ and 0.02-¹ s. Is it safe to say Fs = 1 / average(dt)

Comment: Yes, that should be an average frequency. That would correspond to *2\*PI rad* in digital domain. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/analog-filters.html) are the functions for creating 1D filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your application I would strongly recommend trying a plain butterworth filter, the Matlab syntax is:

```
[b,a]=butter(n,Wn)
```

Where `Wn` is the digital frequency, so here's how I would pose it:

```
% assume x is time and y is speed
Ts = mean(diff(x));
Fs = 1/Ts;
% for butter, we need Wn, which is the cutoff frequency
% where 0.0 < Wn < 1.0, where 1.0 is half the sample rate
% The cutoff is the -3 dB point of the filter
% Wn = fCutOff/(Fs/2)
% for a cutoff of 12 Hz
fCutOff = 12/(Fs/2);
% we'll start with an order of 1 which should give us about 20 db/decade attenuation
[b,a] = butter(1,fCutoff);
% plot the filter frequency response to see what it looks like
% use 512 points to plot it
freqz(b,a,512,Fs)
```

However, if, I understand correctly, you're sampling the data at about 66 Hz, which is about 5 times faster than your desired cutoff.  Rule of thumb is often 10 times, so you may not be real happy with what you get as output.  Here's my output: [image: results]